# Sorting some amounts in ascending order in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to sort some values (distances) in an ascending order but it didn't work, I have tried this:

```
    for (ChargingSpots *spot in chSpot)
    {
        CLLocation *thePoint = ([[CLLocation alloc]initWithLatitude:[spot.LocationLat doubleValue] longitude:[spot.LocationLong doubleValue]]);
        CLLocationDistance distance = [thePoint distanceFromLocation:currentLocation];
//        spot.currentDistance = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:distance];
         spot.currentDistance = @(distance);
//        NSLog(@"%@",dist);
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"currentDistance" ascending:YES];
    [chSpot sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

What I am trying to do is put the distances in an array then sort them in an ascending order.
Then I want to make a zoom on the nearest 3,

```
for (int i=0; i<chSpot.count; i++)
{
    ChargingSpots *spot = [chSpot objectAtIndex:i];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        bounds = [bounds includingCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([spot.LocationLat doubleValue],[spot.LocationLong doubleValue])];
    }


    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
                                                            longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
                                                                 zoom:4];
    mapView_.camera = camera;

}
```

Comment: `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` returns a `NSArray` sorted. Return value that you don't use. If you want to keep `chSpot` and if it's a `NSMutableArray`, use `sortUsingDescriptors:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"currentDistance"
                                          ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [chSpot sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Updated Answer for zooming

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor;
sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"currentDistance"
                                          ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray;
sortedArray = [chSpot sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:[[sortedArray firstObject] valueForKey:@"latitude"]
                                                        longitude:[[sortedArray firstObject] valueForKey:@"longitude"]
                                                             zoom:4];
mapView_.camera = camera;
```

Comment: great, thanks a lot.
Now i have one more issue, I need to make a zoom on the least 3 spots (nearest)

Comment: Change the map location to that point and after that change zoom level on the map

Comment: I modified my code so that you can check the way I am trying to do but doesn't work because i can't end my loop...take a look

Comment: You shouldn't initialise the camera with in the for loop, check the updated answer

Comment: the problem with this is the loop doesn't end with 3, it gives me all the elements which are 21

Comment: you have used 'i' for both the for loop:P

Answer (score 0):

Hey I think that you did not put the distances in an array. You modified the current instance but did not update the cgSpot array.